# How to properly connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was following along in an expressjs exercise that shows how to connect to mongodb. when I run my the app.js file, I get the following message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lBaM.jpg)

It's supposed to show my console.log message of "'MongoDB Conneced....'" to show that it's connected but it's not.

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

//Map global promise - get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vidjot-dev')
.then(()=>console.log('MongoDB Conneced....'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'main'
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
const myTitle="Welcome.";
res.render('INDEX', {
    title:myTitle
});
});

//About Route
app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
   res.render('ABOUT');
})
const port = 5500;
app.listen(port, ()=> {
console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);

/*Same as above which is ES6 */
//console.log('Server started on port '+port);
})
```

Comment: is mongodb started? on your terminal

Comment: How do you start it?  I wasn't show how to start it on the terminal

Comment: Actually, I get a new error when I fixed a typo.  I will update the question

Comment: Start that mongo service, then check whether mongodb is working or not ? then run the project.

Comment: I'm on a windows 7 machine

Comment: when I type "mongod" in the terminal.  I get bash: command not found

Comment: Did you install mongodb? on your system 

Comment: If you type mongod and the command isn't found, you either haven't installed it, or the path to mongo binaries isn't in your path variables

Comment: I will reinstall and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the mongodb in your system and then set its path. 
Finally, just run the command in the terminal `mongod` 

Note: also make a folder the for the database as it ask you to create for example : c:/db.

Then try to connect it again